# VSCode no autocompleta en javascript

Tags: javascript, vscode

Se que no está muy relacionado con el foro pero Tengo un problema con el auto completado en VSCode y es que hay veces que no me auto-completa como si lo hace WebStorn, no se a qué se debe esto pero la verdad no quisiera cambiarme a WebStorn estoy muy contento con VSCode y quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de resolver esto o instalar algún complemento.

Aquí les dejo una imagen para que vean el problema y la diferencia entre VSCode y WebStorn:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @Riven, me parece que el main de abajo es de Webstorm, mientras el de arriba es el de vscode.

Comment: Si correcto, y en vscode no me autocmpleta

Comment: Daniel. Recuerda que Estás comparando un editor de texto con un IDE. Hay muchísimas características que vienen incluidos en IDEs como WebStorm, que no hallarás en editores como vsCode. Te comparto un link[https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/FAQ#_what-is-the-difference-between-visual-studio-code-and-visual-studio-ide] donde puedes ver la diferencia.

Comment: Y no puedo tener ese autocompletado nisiqueira con los plugins.?

Comment: Una pregunta, tú dices que "hay veces" que no autocompleta. Esto significa que NUNCA autocompleta, o, SÍ lo hace pero en ocasiones no funciona? Porque, la función de la que hablas, Intellisense, ya viene incluída (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense)

Comment: Pues no auto-completa cuando por ejemplo pongo el "addEventListener" dentro de una variable como se ve en el ejemplo, pero si lo pongo solo sin haber nada si aparece el auto-completado. Nose a que se deba pero no me gusta eso. Quienes mas usan VSCode quisiera saber si tienen el mismo problema

Answer (score 1):

1)Revisa si tienes algún tipo de extensión que a veces puede estar funcionando como no debe.

2)Puedes entrar a las configuraciones de visual y en el buscador, escribe intellisense y verifica que todo esté bien.

3)Si presionas Ctrl+ ESPACIO, carga todas las propiedades que tiene que ver con los que estás escribiendo.

Me pasaba y con la 3 lo solucione.